# How to create Multiple Store with different domain in Magento

Tags: magento-1.7, multistore, store-view

How to create multiple stores with different domains in Magento with same products, same database but different customers.

Example :

I bought 2 domains: **mystore1.com** and **mystore2.com** (FYI: mystore1.com already running)

Now I want to add **mystore2.com** to **mystore2.com** with same products, same database but different customers.

**Notes:**

- Already tested with [This Way](http://www.templatemonster.com/help/magento-how-to-set-up-and-manage-multiple-stores.html)
- Please answer **step by step** !! **Bounty** for a correct answer.
  and do **not** answer with referral link.

Comment: so is that tutorial which you followed work?
if yes: Is your problem related with using different customers for different stores?

Comment: i don't want to change  index.php.

Comment: you don't need to change the main index.php, you should only change the index.php of mstore2.

You can try the tut linked by Marius

Comment: correct @Shathish . It's already established, but now the problem is  : "NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://mystore2.com/"

Comment: is mystore2.com working independently? if it works, then the problem may be with .htaccess, which u configured

Answer (score 28, accepted):

**Preconditions**
Magento already created a default website on installation (in your case mystore1.com).
**Step 1 - Creation**
Go to `System->Manage Stores`. Click on **Create Website**. Fill in the the form with desired values and save. Example:

- Name - Website 2
- Code - site2
- Sort Order: 2

Click on **Create Store**. In the form fill in the values and save. Example:

- Website - Website 2 (the one you created previously)
- Store for website 2
- Root Category - Default Category (same as the store in mystore1.com)

Click on **Create Store View**. In the form fill in the values and save. Example:

- Store
- Name - store for website 2  (the one you created above)
- Code - store2
- Status - Enabled
- Sort Order - 1

So far you have created a new website.
**Step 2 - Configuration**
Go to `System->Configuration->Web->Unsecure`. From the top left dropdown select 'Website 2' (the website not the store view) and fill the following value.

- Base URL : http://www.mysite2.com/
- Base Link URL: {{unsecure_base_url}}
- Base Skin URL: {{unsecure_base_url}}skin/
- Base Media URL: {{unsecure_base_url}}media/
- Base JavaScript URL: {{unsecure_base_url}}js/
  If some of them are already like that, leave them that way.

If you plan to use SSL on your website you should do the same on the `Secure` section but fill in the secure url of your website for 'Base URL'.

- Base URL : https://www.mysite2.com/
- Base Link URL: {{secure_base_url}}
- Base Skin URL: {{secure_base_url}}skin/
- Base Media URL: {{secure_base_url}}media/
- Base JavaScript URL: {{secure_base_url}}js/

Save the changes and clear the cache.

**Step 3 - Server configuration**
Now you have to make the document root of mysite2.com point to the same folder as mysite1.com.

Add this to your `httpd.conf` file

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@mysite2.com
    DocumentRoot /document/root/here
    ServerName mysite2.com
</VirtualHost>
```

Now when you visit mysite2.com you will see the same homepage as mysite1.com but the first click you make will take you to mysite1.com.
To fix this add the following to `.htaccess`.

```
SetEnvIf Host www\.mysite1\.com MAGE_RUN_CODE=base #or the code for mysite1.com
SetEnvIf Host www\.mysite1\.com MAGE_RUN_TYPE=website
SetEnvIf Host ^mysite1\.com MAGE_RUN_CODE=base #or the code for mysite1.com
SetEnvIf Host ^mysite1\.com MAGE_RUN_TYPE=website

SetEnvIf Host www\.mysite2\.com MAGE_RUN_CODE=site2 #or the code for mysite1.com
SetEnvIf Host www\.mysite2\.com MAGE_RUN_TYPE=website
SetEnvIf Host ^mysite2\.com MAGE_RUN_CODE=site2 #or the code for mysite1.com
SetEnvIf Host ^mysite2\.com MAGE_RUN_TYPE=website
```

Restart the server, clear the cache again just in case (contents of var/cache) and you should be ready.

In case I missed something you can check [this tutorial](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/tutorial-multi-site-multi-domain-setup) that basically says the same things.

**[EDIT]**
After configuring the new website, in order to separate the customers go to `System->Configuration->Customer Configuration->Account Sharing Options` and set the value for **Share Customer Accounts** to **Per website**.

Comment: how about configuration with nginx?

Comment: I have no (valuable) experience with nginx, but the first thing that google came up with is: http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/1_-_installation_and_configuration/configuring_nginx_for_magento Give it a try.

Comment: Is it impossible to work with 2 separate web servers (each with a different domain) ?