# Magento multistore mixed url structure

Tags: magento-1.9, multistore, url, ce-1.9.1.0

I'm looking around to see if this is possible but have not found anyone explicitly stating it as such.

What I want to know is can I have a Magento multi store setup where one store is on a subdomain, one on the main domain and one on a completely different domain but all pointing to the same Magento.

My Magento install is 1.9.1

Alternatively if this is not possible, how much work is involved in changing the whole multisite to use just the different domain names option from currently using the sub domains set up.

Comment: does this help? http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/4753/146

Answer (score 0):

It is posible, in the link below you will find everything you need:

https://www.crucialhosting.com/knowledgebase/setup-multiple-magento-stores#url-structure