# Why my multistore (www.domain2.com) still redirect to www.domain1.com?

Tags: multistore

I made a website www.domain1.com

and I also a multistore to different domain in magento that is www.domain2.com.

My question is : 
Why my multistore (www.domain2.com) still redirect to www.domain1.com ?

Can you help me ?

I want every multistore to be standalone and not redirect in www.domain1.com but in one data base (magento Multistore).

Answer (score 0):

Have you set $_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_CODE'] and $_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_TYPE'] for both domains?

See here for a full expaination
[How to create Multiple Store with different domain in Magento](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/4750/how-to-create-multiple-store-with-different-domain-in-magento)

Comment: Yes I have set it . But why in cms page / product category still redirect to the domain 1 ? and not stand alone same like home page (Domain 2) ... Please Help me (T_T)

Comment: If the home page loads for domain2, but any links to category or CMS pages switch back to domain1 then it sounds like it's the domain URLs set within the admin for the second store.

Go to 
System > Configuration > General > Web,
Select domain2 in the dropdown (top right),
Check Base URL in unsecure and secure sections.