# Magento - Multiple Store - 2 domains, but 2nd store is in a subfolder

Tags: multistore, 404-page, .htaccess

I have 2 stores:

- domain.ca
- domain.com (Domain Alias to /usa subfolder)

domain.ca is already working and online. I'm trying to add domain.com to as an additional store.

I've setup the Admin part.

What I want to do is to:

- have index.php and .htaccess in a separate folder -> /usa and have that folder use symlinks or w/e to get it's skin/app/etc/media folders.

I've setup the symlinks in that folder, but they are throwing 404 error when i go to domain.com

I've tested symlinks through FTP and SSH both worked.

I wonder maybe because I created them as root account, they are not working?

Is there a way to make this method work?

I have made the normal method without subfolder work, but we have a live site and some customers have squeezed through to domain.com by mistake - I want to limit their access to domain.com so its blocked until the site is ready.

Plus this will allow extra mobility when I make changes to either store.

Edit:
Webserver that I'm using is Litespeed, im not sure if that makes any difference or not.

Comment: seems like this response can you help http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/4750/how-to-create-multiple-store-with-different-domain-in-magento?rq=1

Comment: I've tried this, it works, but that is NOT what I need. I need to run 2 different index.php and .htaccess files, so that I could block traffic coming to the 2nd site. 2nd site has to be inside of /public_html/usa subfolder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok looks like it wanted me to change permissions on the files.

the user and group of the links must match the permissions of the files in main directory.

I just ran:
chown -R user:user app

All good now!

PS: the way I created symlinks was:

ln -s ../app app

EDIT:

then i had to make sure the User:Group matches to the webserver after creating symlinks:

chown -h user:group symboliclink